# Pyinstaller failed to made exe out of script

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller on my system was working fine but after I tried to install google.colab which didn't went through, I am getting error and its failing everytime on several files. I've no idea what went wrong and I even tried to re install all my modules but still getting this error. I searched all over stackoverflow but didn't find the answer or similar question.Here is the error log. Any help would be appreciated.

````
393 INFO: Python: 3.10.1
411 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
411 INFO: wrote C:\Users\dell\Desktop\ZillowAddres\New folder\ZILLOWADDRESS.spec
416 INFO: UPX is not available.
432 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\ZillowAddres\\New folder']
833 INFO: checking Analysis
834 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
834 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
837 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
849 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5704 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
5705 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
6927 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7134 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7150 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
7204 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\dell\Desktop\ZillowAddres\New folder\ZILLOWADDRESS.py
8174 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
13593 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
13594 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
21345 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py:130: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if group is 'connector_python':
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\optionfiles.py:98: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if group is 'connector_python':
37892 INFO: Processing module hooks...
37893 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
37899 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
38167 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 27, in <module>
    import resource
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 46, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.timing import clock, clock2
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 64, in <module>
    clocku = clocks = clock = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 27, in <module>
    import resource
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pkgutil.py", line 495, in find_loader
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 46, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.timing import clock, clock2
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 64, in <module>
    clocku = clocks = clock = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 365, in get_module_file_attribute
    loader = pkgutil.find_loader(package)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pkgutil.py", line 501, in find_loader
    raise ImportError(msg.format(fullname, type(ex), ex)) from ex
ImportError: Error while finding loader for 'IPython.extensions' (<class 'AttributeError'>: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 606, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-IPython.py", line 34, in <module>
    datas += collect_data_files('IPython.extensions', include_py_files=True)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 723, in collect_data_files
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths(package)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 518, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 383, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError('Unable to load module attribute') from e
ImportError: Unable to load module attribute

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 793, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\ZillowAddres\New folder\ZILLOWADDRESS.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['ZILLOWADDRESS.py'],
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 445, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 364, in _load_hook_module
    raise ImportErrorWhenRunningHook(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_IPython required by hook for module C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-IPython.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_IPython actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-IPython.py: You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.```
````

Comment: Was there an option to include/not include python standard libraries? I haven't used PyInstaller, but it seems like that would be an option so that it didn't include them if it doesn't need to.

Comment: No, There is no option

Answer (score 0):

Initial review it looks like Ipython might be outdated or out of synch. Here are my suggestions:

1. Apologies, but first I have to ask; does your python script package run properly outside of pyinstaller? If not, please share any other errors you are receiving.
2. Confirm that your IPython version is not outdated. If outdated pip install latest version.
3. Try reinstalling pip
4. Check in pysintaller output logs if you have them available to see if python version has changed since last build. I recently had to issue with 3.10 and I had setup an virtual environment with 3.9.10.
5. If none of this works, please share pyinstaller spec file and requirements.txt for further assistance if possible.

Best of luck!